# What is the proper way to install an ubuntu kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04, perf

Some suggest with `apt-get install`, while others with `dpkg -i *.deb` after downloading the necessary files. I mostly use the latter approach without knowing the difference with the former.

- Can someone highlight the difference between the two command lines?
- Which one is more appropriate?
- What is the exact command line to install fully, say `4.4.0-64 kernel` for example?

I downloaded the 4.6 deb's from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/ then run `dpkg -i *.deb`.
However,  I am not able to run `perf top` command line. `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-4.6.0-040600-generic` does not work, to install perf.. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**apt-get** is a Package Management System that handles the installation of Deb packages on Debian-based Linux distributions. A Package Management System is a set of tools that will help you install, remove, and change packages easily. So `apt-get` is like a clever dpkg.

**dpkg** only installs a package, so doing `dpkg -i *.deb` will only install this Deb package, and will notify you of any dependencies that need to be installed, but it will not install them, and it will not configure the ***.deb** because the dependencies are not there.

As per my knowledge perf is independent of the kernel.Even you can compile it with the latest kernel;

```
cd linux/tools/perf
make
cp perf /usr/bin
```

But if you want it with **apt-get install** command
then first of all find out your kernel version through `uname -r` command and try with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-<version_number>
```

Follow this link for more understanding.

[difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get)